# What is the best way to perform operations on a newly assigned variable in dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-manipulation, piping

How to avoid assigning a value to a variable, then calling it separately right after to manipulate it? (Like so:)

```
df.3 <- filter(df.1, !(Patient_ID %in% df.2))

df.3 %>%  count(MIPSGroup)
```

The only way I know how to do it is:

```
(df.3 <- filter(df.1, !(Patient_ID %in% df.2))) %>%
   df.3 %>%  count(MIPSGroup)
```

But there's gotta be a better way...

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, can't you just `filter(df.1, !(Patient_ID %in% df.2)) %>% count(MIPSGroup)`

Comment: Yes, but I want to save the `filter`ed output from `df.1` before `count`ing.

Comment: I don't think it is particularity bad writing an extra line of code, but you pipe the next chunks with things like `assign(x = "df.3", envir = .GlobalEnv)` or `{df.3 <<- .}`

Comment: I think you're not understanding the purpose of the `%>%`. You can do `df.3 <- filter(df.1, !(Patient_ID %in% df.2)) %>% count(MIPSGroup)`. Here's a reproducible example: `mtcars %>% filter(cyl==6) %>% count(mpg)`

Comment: But that saves the counts matrix into df.3, not the filtered df.2.

Comment: All that it really saves you is lines-of-code-golf, but `count((df3 <- filter(mtcars, cyl==4)), am)` or perhaps `(df3 <- filter(mtcars, cyl==4)) %>% count(am)`.

Comment: Intended to write above, left out some details. `filter(df.1, !(Patient_ID %in% df.2)) %>% {df.3 <<- .} %>% count(MIPSgroup)` or `filter(df.1, !(Patient_ID %in% df.2)) %>% assign(x = "df.3", envir = .GlobalEnv) %>% count(MIPSgroup)`

Answer (score 1):

If you were willing to modify the original input, you could use `magrittr`'s `%<>%` (compound assignment) operator:

```
(mtcars %<>% filter(cyl==6)) %>% count(mpg)
```

This modifies the value of `mtcars` according to the filter and prints the results of the `count` operation on the result.

There may be some way to use `magrittr`'s other operators (e.g. `%T>%`) to get this done, but I haven't figured it out yet. I tried

```
((mtcars -> tmpcars) %<>% filter(cyl==6)) %>% count(mpg)
```

but R's parsing magic can't quite handle it.